# read html from C# win forms

Tags: c#, html

I need to read title of the web site using C# win forms.so what is the best way to do it.i search on the google but i didnt get anyone.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the WebClient object found in the System.Net.WebClient namespace.

```
using System.Net;
```

With WebClient you can download a whole website as a string and then do whatever you want with that string. :)

Example:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient(); 
string content = wc.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
```

Then just parse the string anyway you want it. :) In this example you might want to find the title element and extract the title  like this:

```
string title = content.Substring(content.IndexOf("<title>"), content.IndexOf("</title>") - content.IndexOf("<title>")).Replace("<title>", "").Trim();
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanku you @peterthegreat.This this snippet really help to me .thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do whole webpage parsing then you can try [HTML Agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). If what you need is just the Title then some Regular Expression will do it.

Since most of the Time Title is in `<title>` tag you can straight away extract that.

For downloading the HTML then you can use a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) or [HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx)/Response objects

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like and use [SgmlReader](http://developer.mindtouch.com/en/docs/SgmlReader) to parse HTML:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using Sgml;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
        using (var reader = new SgmlReader())
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(client.OpenRead(url)))
        {
            reader.DocType = "HTML";
            reader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.All;
            reader.CaseFolding = Sgml.CaseFolding.ToLower;
            reader.InputStream = streamReader;

            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
            doc.XmlResolver = null;
            doc.Load(reader);
            var title = doc.SelectSingleNode("//title");
            if (title != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(title.InnerText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```